# Will I be able to access a bookmark faster if I store its ip address instead of hostname in the bookmark?

Tags: dns, ip-address, hostname

If I want to visit https://stackoverflow.com/teams/use-cases.

1) Will it be faster if I visit it via
`https://151.101.129.69/teams/use-cases` instead because it skips the DNS look up for `stackoverflow.com` to `151.101.129.69`?

2) Why does Firefox display a "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead" page and not allowing me to go to the page successfully directly?

3) Why am I not able to reach the page using the URL that contains the IP address? It shows `Fastly error: unknown domain: 151.101.129.69. Please check that this domain has been added to a service.`

Thanks!

Comment: DNS have caches, and the round trip time, in nominal case, is certainly the small portion of the total time to get the content, hence you basically gain nothing in the long run, besides all the problem you will get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (web)server running on one IP address can host multiple websites, so it relies on domain name you typed in your address bar to determine which website you wanted to access.

When you take the above into account,

1. In some cases yes, but most of the time that will just not work. Even if it works, performance improvement will be negligible (unless you have some serious 
   issues with your DNS infrastructure).
2. HTTPS requires that the domain name you typed in your browsr matches the domain name in the certificate on server side, `stackoverflow.com != 151.101.129.69` so you get the warning
3. Server just does not know which website to serve, there is no website with name "151.101.129.69" configured there